# Decision tree on big categorical dataset

Tags: decision-trees

I would like to use algorithm ID3 in order to find a decision tree of my [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/chocolate-bar-ratings). I would like to see which of the attributes and values lead to the different value of rating (1<= x <= 5). Do you think it is possible to do it? I got stucked but I don't know if it is because it is not a possible thing to do or it is my fault as a beginner. Can you give me some advise or hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this dataset as a regression problem and not a classification one. The label is ordered, so predicting 2.8 is not a mistake, it is just that it is close to 3 (satisfactory but not there).

I can suggest to start with a regression tree and then round the results to have integers.

Also you can consider this a multiclassification task, but as a starter I would go with regression.

Comment: Thank you very much @Carlos